# In GNOME, how to move and resize window using one hotkey like Xfce (Alt) or elementary OS (Super)?

Tags: gnome3, desktop-environment

In Xfce, we can hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, and use the left mouse button to move the window, or use the right mouse button to resize the window. Similarly, in elementary OS there is the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, but in GNOME, how do you set the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to drag or resize window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run GNOME Tweaks, go to the “Windows” section, and choose your favourite action key next to the “Window Action Key” entry:

[image: The “Windows” section of GNOME Tweaks]

Pressing the action key will allow you to move windows (using the main mouse button) and resize them (using the middle mouse button).